# How to enable auto update the client logics when changing ES6 code in development environment?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Problem: I'm learning ES6 through playing around with the code. I found that it's quite annoying to rebuild and restart the server every time I made any changes.

Goal: I want the changes that I saved to be reflected on the browser, without having to manually rebuild, and restart the server. What's the simplest way to do that?

Background: 
The current script configuration in the package.json file is as below.

```
"scripts": {
   "babel": "babel --presets es2015 js/main.js -o build/main.bundle.js",
   "start": "http-server -p 9000" 
},
```

I hope this is clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must be using `gulp` tasks to run your project. If so, `browser-sync` + `gulp.watch()` is the best option for this. Below is what working for me, add something like below to your `gulp` task .js file. Whenever you change and save your `es6` source code, it will automatically build and refresh the browser.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browser     = require('browser-sync').create();

// your default task goes here that should add "watch-changes" as dependency

// watch changes in js and html files
gulp.task('watch-changes', function() {
     browser.init({
       // initiate your browser here, refer browser-sync website
      });
    gulp.watch(
        ['build/main.bundle.js', 'webapp/**/*.html'],
        browser.reload);
});
```

Check [here](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp) neat example.

Refer [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/) website and [npm gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) task